# Getting error "<name>.dll is not a Win32 application" when launching application from IDE

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2015

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 on a 64-bit Windows 7 installation.  I am trying to launch code from the IDE.

When I run the code I get the error that `shapeAPI.dll` is not a win32 application.  In the `project >properties > configuration manager`  I have both the active solution platform, and the project solution platform set to win32.  I don't have a ton of experience with Visual Studio or such errors, and most of the threads I looked through didn't seem to have solutions that worked.

What is causing the error and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Usually that means that the loader is resolving one of the dependencies by finding a DLL with the wrong bitness.  Either 32 bit in 64 bit process or vice versa. Use Dependency Viewer in profile mode to find out what exactly the loader is doing and which DLL fails to load.

Comment: You cannot execute a DLL. You must launch an EXE instead. Likely reason: You have a solution with multiple projects, and didn't set the *StartUp Project* to point to the project that compiles to an EXE.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to run a DLL (dynamic link library) as an executable, which you cannot do.  It's possible you're running the wrong file.  You may have an executable that depends on shapeAPI.dll.  Or maybe your project settings are set to create a DLL instead of an executable.  There's not enough info here to diagnose.

Comment: It is not a bitness problem, that fails with a different error.  Run Dumpbin.exe /headers on the DLL and show us what you see.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the issue.  I had a visual studios project designed to create a dll.  I was trying to run it as a standalone application.  Hence the errors I was recieving.  By switching the visual studios project to a windows application then compiled it and ran the basic test sequence in the code without spitting out errors.  Thanks for your responses it helped point me in the direction to find the solution.